# pandas column data as marker in plot?

Tags: python, pandas

the code below plots the data with the marker as a green spot. BUT I want the marker to be the actual value of y. So instead of the green dots the marker would be 10, 22.5, 43.34.  Anyone done this please?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


x = [ 10,20,30] 
y = [ 10,22.5 ,43.34 ]

x_new = 100
y_new = np.interp(x_new, x, y)

print(y_new)

plt.plot(x, y, "og-");

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are looking for `annotate` instead:

```
plt.plot(x, y, "og-",markersize=40);

for xx,yy in zip(x,y):
    plt.annotate(f'{yy}', (xx, yy), va='center',ha='center', color='w')
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: thank you so much AGAIN!!! I didn't even know annotate existed.  I REALLY have to read the docs more. Thanks again. I have to mod the answer as I am using plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=1) and .plot(ax=axes[0] ) thanks again for such wonderful help